# Asymmetric encryption generating as small output (in bytes) as it is possible?

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

I have to incorporate rsa encryption in my application. 
I will have public and private keys. The problem is I need to store sensitive data on sql ce database on mobile device. I need to encrypt relatively small strings, e.g. up to 20, 30 chars, but there is lots of them. Later they will have to be uploaded.

I have tested RSA encryption. For 20 bytes source I get 172 bytes encrypted on output.
Is it possible to go down with the output length?

Bit strength I've chosen is 1024.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The length of your output is directly linked to you key size.

The only way to shorten it is to use a weaker key.

A practical approach could be to somehow combine short fields (to just under the keysize).

Comment: Or use another encryption method

Comment: But if he uses a weaker key, he can't encrypt long strings ? I'm not the OP but I'd like to know (Bad Length cryptographic exception in .Net)

Comment: RSA with keys smaller than 1024 bits is not terribly reassuring.

Comment: @Nacereddine - When the message is longer than the key it needs to be split, but RSA is not commonly used for this.

Comment: @SynerCoder Which one would give me the expected results? (Just need the functionality with public/private keys)

Comment: @John I dont know exactly, but .net provides those asym methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.aspx (check childs)

Answer (score 0):

The encrypted result is affected by padding, so you might want to cut down on this overhead by

- Grouping strings together and encrypting them as one item
- Toggle the second parameter of [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx)